# Why are these resistors not in series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image] this is the circuit in question.

I treated $R_1$ and $R_2$ as resistors in series, and $R_3$ and $R_4$ as resistors in series. Then the equivalent resistors were combined in parallel. However, this is wrong. Could someone explain why?

Comment: *Why am I getting an incorrect value?* In general, check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: *1 / (1/R1+R2 + 1/R3+R4))* Without some additional parentheses, that isn’t dimensionally consistent.

Comment: Why do you think that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are in series? Does all the current through $R_1$ also flow through $R_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Two resistors, R1 and R2, are in series to form an equivalent resistor, R1 + R2, only if the current in R1 equals the current in R2.  This requires that there are no alternative paths / nodes in the circuit for the current leaving R1 to flow through instead of passing through R2.  In the circuit that you've drawn, there is an alternative path through R3 so R1 and R2 are not in series.

Answer (score 1):

$R_1$ and $R_2$ are **not** in series. $R_1$ is in series with $R_{234}$.

To see why, I like to imagine a single charge wondering through the circuit. The charge, starting from the battery,  will either go through $R_2$ **or** ($R_3$ and $R_4$), but *no matter what*, for it to return back to the battery, must go through $R_1$. Therefore, $R_1$ is in series with the equivalent resistor $R_{234}$.

First, combine $R_3$ and $R_4$ to get $R_{34}$. Next, combine $R_2$ and $R_{34}$ to get $R_{234}$. Lastly, combine $R_1$ with $R_{234}$ to get $R_\mathrm{eq}$.